# Not providing db credentials in quartz config

Tags: configuration, quartz-scheduler, credentials

I am using quartz in a web application and using `QuartzInitializerServlet`.

Now to run it on multiple systems, I have added a database to make it run it in clustered mode. The dataSource properties are provided in quartz.properties file but this exposes the database credentials in cleartext.

Is there some way to use `QuartzInitializerServlet` but provide the `dataSource` credentials through code (where I can retrieve the credentials stored elsewhere) ?

Comment: If you are using Spring you can provide any *instance* of `DataSource`, e.g. obtained via JNDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation : http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigDataSources.html#configure-datasources

Use the jndiUrl property to specify the jndi name of your datasource:

```
org.quartz.dataSource.NAME.jndiURL = java:comp/env/jdbc/www_datasource
```

HIH